# SQL Select в несколько таблиц в одном запросе

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

у меня есть запрос

```
<?php $sql_ee = "SELECT * FROM `app_catalog_turbokompressor` WHERE `ee` LIKE '%$request%' ORDER BY `number` $order"; $result_ee = $data_base_CONNECT->query($sql_ee); ?>
```

Пробовал делать так

```
<?php $sql_ee = "SELECT * FROM `app_catalog_turbokompressor`, `app_catalog_rotor` WHERE `ee` LIKE '%$request%' ORDER BY `number` $order"; $result_ee = $data_base_CONNECT->query($sql_ee); ?>
```

Но тогда запрос не работает.

**Как я могу сделать SELECT сразу из 2 или 3 или более таблиц в одном запросе?**

Вот пример запроса в phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT * FROM `app_catalog_turbokompressor`, `app_catalog_rotor` WHERE `ee` LIKE '%-002%' ORDER BY `number` ASC
```

Вернуло

```
#1146 - Таблица 'turboam.app_catalog_rotor' не существует
```

Comment: что подразумевается под словами "не работает"?

Comment: почитайте про join https://shra.ru/2017/09/sql-join-v-primerakh-s-opisaniem/

Comment: @AzizUmarov ему тут очевидно нужен UNION а не join

Comment: *тогда запрос не работает* Это невозможно. Либо запрос выполняется, но результат отличается от ожидаемого (тогда хотя бы следует продемонстрировать, что вернулось и что ожидалось), либо вызывает ошибку (и возвращается сообщение об ошибке - тогда следует полностью воспроизвести это сообщение).

Comment: Добавил в вопрос, то что вернулось

Comment: Что подразумевается под словами "сразу из 2 или 3 или более таблиц в одном запросе"? Чля чего эти таблицы добавлять в запрос? С какойстати это вдруг понадобилось?